# Access enum inside an interface

Tags: java, interface, enums

I am completely new to Java. I have an interface that has a few methods that I need to implement. Inside the interface, there is a class that has enums that I need to access.

It looks like this:

```
public interface Operations{
    //some function names that I have to implement
    public static enum ErrorCodes{
        BADFD;
        NOFILE;
        ISDIR;
        private ErrorCode{
        }
    }
}
```

In my implementation, when I try to access `ErrorCodes.BADFD` it gives me error. I do not know the right way to access it. Also, what is the empty `private ErrorCode{}` called. Is it the constructor? What does it do?

EDIT : added uppercase 'o' to enum name

Comment: I think there is a typo error in your code. Enum name is ErrorCodes but you are trying to call ErrorCode.BADFD. Try calling ErrorCodes.BADFD

Comment: `static enum` and `private` constructor is redundant since all inner enum types are implicitly static, and enum constructors are also implicitly private.

Comment: There is another typo in your `enum` constructor. `private ErrorCode{` should be `private ErrorCode() {`

Comment: Also java is casesensitive so it should be `interface` not `Interface`

Comment: @Pshemo You're right. That was typo. Although I see ErrorCodes indeed is public static

Comment: Another problem is that you are separating your enum values with `;` instead of comma `,`. And constructors can also handle arguments so even if you din't want to pass them add `()` to their declaration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let's correct your malformed code:

```
// lowercase "interface"
// Usually interfaces and classes are capitalized
public interface Operations{
    // Singular to match the rest of the code and question.
    public static enum ErrorCode{
        // commas to separate instances
        BADFD,
        NOFILE,
        ISDIR;
        // Parameterless constructor needs ()
        private ErrorCode() {
        }
    }
}
```

To reference `ErrorCode` outside of the interface, you must qualify it with `ErrorCode`'s enclosing interface, `Operations`.

```
Operations.ErrorCode code = Operations.ErrorCode.BADFD;
```

Comment: Or `ErrorCode.BADFD` if you import `Operations.ErrorCode`. ---  Or `BADFD` if you *statically* import `Operations.ErrorCode.BADFD`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the corrected one

```
public interface Operations{
//some function names that I have to implement
public static enum ErrorCodes{
    BADFD,
    NOFILE,
    ISDIR;
    private ErrorCodes(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to call the enum this way :

`Operations.ErrorCode.BADFD`

Because ErrorCode is an inner enum of the Operation interface.

I noticed few typo problems, take a look at this code :

```
public interface Operations {
    //some function names that I have to implement
    public static enum ErrorCode {
        BADFD,
        NOFILE,
        ISDIR;
        private ErrorCode() {
        }
    }
}
```